# Не могу найти ошибку при удалении элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, прошу помочь найти ошибку в коде. Уже весь день просидел, так и не понял как решить проблему. 
Ошибка заключается в том, что после добавления элементов, неправильно удаляются элементы по клику. Удаляется не выбранный элемент. Почему-то удаление начинается с 1 элемента. При удалении через кнопку "Clear Completed" при выборе выбранных, удаляются так же не выбранные элементы, а произвольные.

```js
var tasks = [];

function UpdateTasks() {
  $('#todo-list').find('li').remove();
  $(tasks).each(function(i, t) {
    $('#todo-list').append('<li class="' + t.status + '">\
            <div class="todo-task">\
            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" data-id="' + t.id + '" ' + (t.status === 'completed' ? ' checked ' : '') + '><label class="text">' + t.title + '</label>\
            <button class="destroy"></button>\
            </div>\
            </li>');
    if ($('#todo-list li').hasClass('completed')) {
      $('#clear-completed').show();
    }
    if (!$('#todo-list li').hasClass('completed')) {
      $('#clear-completed').hide();
    }
  });
  ShowTasksCounter();
}

function ShowTasksCounter() {
  $('.count').text(tasks.length);
  if (tasks.length < 1) {
    $('#footer').hide();
  }
}

/* Добавление задач */

$('#new-todo').keyup(function(e) {
  const newId = GetNewUserId();
  if ((e.keyCode === 13)) {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      $('#main').show();
      $('#footer').show();
      var $this = $(this);
      var newTask = $this.val();
      tasks.push({
        id: newId,
        title: newTask,
        status: 'active'
      });
      UpdateTasks();
      // Очистка Input
      $('#new-todo').val('');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});

/* Генерация id */

function GetNewUserId() {
  var maxId = tasks.reduce((max, item) => item.id > max ? item.id : max, 0);
  return maxId + 1;
}

/* Checkbox */

$('#todo-list').on('click', '.toggle', function(e) {
  var id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id + 1);
  tasks[id].status = "completed";
  if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
    tasks[id].status = "active";
  }
  UpdateTasks();
});

$('#toggle-all').on('click', function() {
  $(tasks).each(function(i) {
    if ($('#toggle-all').prop("checked")) {
      tasks[i].status = "completed";
    } else {
      tasks[i].status = "active";
    }
  });
  UpdateTasks();
});

/* Отображение выбранных задач */

$('.show-all-tasks').on('click', function() {
  $('li.active').show();
  $('li.completed').show();
  $(this).toggleClass('activated');
  $('.show-active-tasks').removeClass('activated');
  $('.show-completed-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

$('.show-active-tasks').on('click', function() {
  $('li.active').show();
  $('li.completed').hide();
  $(this).toggleClass('activated');
  $('.show-all-tasks').removeClass('activated');
  $('.show-completed-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

$('.show-completed-tasks').on('click', function() {
  $('li.active').hide();
  $('li.completed').show();
  $(this).toggleClass('activated');
  $('.show-all-tasks').removeClass('activated');
  $('.show-active-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

/* Удаление */

$('#todo-list').on('click', 'button.destroy', function(e) {
  var id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
  tasks.splice(id, 1);
  console.log(id);
  UpdateTasks();
});

function ShowTasks() {
  tasks.forEach(function(item, i, tasks) {
    console.log(tasks[i].id, tasks[i].title, tasks[i].status);
  });
}

/* События кнопки Clear Completed */

$('#clear-completed').on('click', function() {
  $('input:checked').parents('li').remove();
  $(tasks).each(function(i) {
    if (tasks[i].status === "completed") {
      tasks.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
  UpdateTasks();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#todo_app {
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 130px 0 40px 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -155px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.15);
}

button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#new-todo {
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 60px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.003);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03)
}

input {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 90;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[placeholder] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

#toggle-all {
  position: absolute;
  top: -55px;
  left: -12px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
}

#toggle-all::before {
  content: "❯";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  padding: 10px 27px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 4px;
  background-color: initial;
  padding: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  font: 13px Arial;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

label[for='toggle-all'] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: default;
}

#todo-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#todo-list li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#todo-list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#todo-list li .toggle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#todo-list li input:checked::after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#bddad5" stroke-width="3"/><path fill="#5dc2af" d="M72 25L42 71 27 56l-4 4 20 20 34-52z"/></svg>');
}

#todo-list li input:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#ededed" stroke-width="3"/></svg>')
}

#todo-list li input:checked+label.text {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#todo-list li label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 15px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}

#todo-list li:hover .destroy {
  display: block;
}

#todo-list li .destroy:hover {}

#todo-list li .destroy {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #cc9a9a;
  margin: auto 0 11px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#todo-list li .destroy::after {
  content: "×";
}


/* Text footer */

#footer {
  color: #777777;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#footer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 8px 0 -3px #f6f6f6, 0 9px 1px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 16px 0 -6px #f6f6f6, 0 17px 2px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.todo-count {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.todo-count strong {
  font-weight: 300;
}

#filters {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul,
menu,
dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

#filters li {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#filters li a.activated {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

#filters li a:active {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

#filters li a:hover {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.1);
}

#filters li a {
  color: inherit;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#clear-completed {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}


/* FOOTER */

footer {
  margin: auto 0;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  line-height: 1;
}

footer a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section id="todo_app">
    <header>
      <input id="new-todo" autofocus>
    </header>
    <section id="main" style="display: none;">
      <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox"> <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
      <ul id="todo-list">
      </ul>
    </section>
    <footer id="footer" style="display: none;">
      <span class="todo-count">
          <strong class="count"> </strong> items left
        </span>
      <ul id="filters">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-all-tasks">All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-active-tasks">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-completed-tasks">Completed</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="clear-completed" style="display: none;">Clear completed</button>
    </footer>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0aw4dw37/3/

Comment: `NaN` в консоли при нажатии `button.destroy` Вам ничего не подсказывает?

Comment: @Igor `parseInt` не может в `Number`. это я знаю. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как исправить ошибки.

Comment: так можно попробовать var id = parseInt(+e.target.dataset.id + 1);

Comment: @Imp3l что значит "`parseInt` не может"? Вы же ожидаете там целое число в строковом виде. Следует разобраться, почему его там нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в этой функции

```
$('#todo-list').on('click', 'button.destroy', function(e) {
  ...
});
```

две ошибки:

*Первая.* Вы берете свойство `data-id` у того элемента, на который нажали. У него этого свойства нет. Это свойство есть у соседнего с ним `".toggle"` под их общим родителем `".todo-task"`.

*Вторая.* Первым параметром метода `Array.splice` должен быть индекс элемента, который Вы хотите удалить, а не какой-то `id`.

Вот как надо:

```
$('#todo-list').on('click', 'button.destroy', function(e) {
  var id = parseInt($(this).closest(".todo-task").find(".toggle").data("id"));
  console.log(id);
  var index = tasks.findIndex(function(item){
    return id == item.id; 
  });
  tasks.splice(index, 1);
  UpdateTasks();
});
```

Comment: при выборе чекбоксом и удалении через кнопку `Clear Completed` все равно криво удаляются элементы

Comment: @Imp3l Вы серьезно? Разве не видно, что я дал Вам код только для кнопки удаления конкретного элемента? Дальше уж Вы постарайтесь сами - по аналогии.

Comment: @Imp3l Вам понятно в чем была Ваша ошибка?

Comment: @Imp3l при чем здесь `parseInt`?

Comment: если честно, я не знаю в чем ошибка

Comment: @Imp3l но если он Вам так нужен, пожалуйста, добавил `parseInt`

Comment: он мне не нужен, я просто хочу разобраться где у меня ошибка

Comment: кнопки удаления индивидуальных элементов списка работают?

Comment: да, работают отлично

Comment: @Imp3l Добавил объяснения в ответ.

Comment: огромное спасибо, жирный плюс вам в карму (:

Comment: @Imp3l Успехов в программировании!

Answer (score 1):

Полностью закинь файл, проверил рабочий. Ошибки были в двух функциях не получал правильные id.  https://jsfiddle.net/0aw4dw37/4/

```
 var tasks = [];

function UpdateTasks () {
    $('#todo-list').find('li').remove();
    $(tasks).each(function (i, t) {
    console.log(t)
        $('#todo-list').append('<li class="' + t.status + '">\
            <div class="todo-task">\
            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" data-id="' + t.id + '" ' + (t.status === 'completed' ? ' checked ' : '' ) + '><label class="text">' + t.title + '</label>\
            <button class="destroy"></button>\
            </div>\
            </li>');
        if ($('#todo-list li').hasClass('completed')) {
            $('#clear-completed').show();
        }
        if (!$('#todo-list li').hasClass('completed')) {
            $('#clear-completed').hide();
        }
    });
    ShowTasksCounter();
}

function ShowTasksCounter() {
    $('.count').text(tasks.length);
    if (tasks.length < 1) {
        $('#footer').hide();
    }
}

/* Добавление задач */

$('#new-todo').keyup(function (e) {
    const newId = GetNewUserId();
    if ((e.keyCode === 13)) {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            $('#main').show();
            $('#footer').show();
            var $this = $(this);
            var newTask = $this.val();
            tasks.push({
                id: newId,
                title: newTask,
                status: 'active'});
            UpdateTasks();
            // Очистка Input
            $('#new-todo').val('');
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});

/* Генерация id */

function GetNewUserId () {
    var maxId = tasks.reduce((max, item) => item.id > max ? item.id : max, 0);
    return maxId + 1;
}

/* Checkbox */

$('#todo-list').on('click', '.toggle', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id') - 1;
    tasks[id].status='completed' ;
    if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
        tasks[id].status = "active";
    }
    UpdateTasks();
});

$('#toggle-all').on('click', function () {
    $(tasks).each(function (i) {
        if ($('#toggle-all').prop("checked")) {
            tasks[i].status = "completed";
        } else {
            tasks[i].status = "active";
        }
    });
    UpdateTasks();
});

/* Отображение выбранных задач */

$('.show-all-tasks').on('click', function() {
    $('li.active').show();
    $('li.completed').show();
    $(this).toggleClass('activated');
    $('.show-active-tasks').removeClass('activated');
    $('.show-completed-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

$('.show-active-tasks').on('click', function() {
    $('li.active').show();
    $('li.completed').hide();
    $(this).toggleClass('activated');
    $('.show-all-tasks').removeClass('activated');
    $('.show-completed-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

$('.show-completed-tasks').on('click', function() {
    $('li.active').hide();
    $('li.completed').show();
    $(this).toggleClass('activated');
    $('.show-all-tasks').removeClass('activated');
    $('.show-active-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

/* Удаление */

$('#todo-list').on('click', 'button.destroy', function (e) {
    var id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
    tasks.splice(id, 1);
    console.log(id);
    UpdateTasks();
});

function ShowTasks () {
    tasks.forEach(function (item, i, tasks) {
        console.log(tasks[i].id, tasks[i].title, tasks[i].status);
    });
}

/* События кнопки Clear Completed */


$('#clear-completed').on('click', function () {
    $('input:checked').parents('li').remove();
    $(tasks).each(function (i,r) {
        //console.log(r)  
        if (r.status === "completed") {
        console.log(tasks.indexOf(r))
            tasks.splice(tasks.indexOf(r), 1);
        }
    });
    UpdateTasks();
});
```

Comment: При удалении через `Clear Completed` нескольких элементов (не всех), удаляются все последующие элементы, начиная с выбранного. А должны удалятся только выбранные

Comment: После удаления нескольких элементов и повторной отметке элементов, они визуально отмечаются, но в массиве они все так же остаются `active`

Answer (score 1):

При удалении у Вас проблема. Вы не получаете нужный индекс. Но и это не все, для метода `splice` нужен правильный индекс, добавил Вам вспомогательную функцию `findIndexElement` на поиск индекса по имени свойства в массиве, в Вашем случае по идентификатору, чтобы удалить из `tasks` правильный элемент.

```js
var tasks = [];

function UpdateTasks() {
  $('#todo-list').find('li').remove();
  $(tasks).each(function(i, t) {
    $('#todo-list').append('<li class="' + t.status + '">\
            <div class="todo-task">\
            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" data-id="' + t.id + '" ' + (t.status === 'completed' ? ' checked ' : '') + '><label class="text">' + t.title + '</label>\
            <button class="destroy"></button>\
            </div>\
            </li>');
    if ($('#todo-list li').hasClass('completed')) {
      $('#clear-completed').show();
    }
    if (!$('#todo-list li').hasClass('completed')) {
      $('#clear-completed').hide();
    }
  });
  ShowTasksCounter();
}

function ShowTasksCounter() {
  $('.count').text(tasks.length);
  if (tasks.length < 1) {
    $('#footer').hide();
  }
}

/* Добавление задач */

$('#new-todo').keyup(function(e) {
  const newId = GetNewUserId();
  if ((e.keyCode === 13)) {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      $('#main').show();
      $('#footer').show();
      var $this = $(this);
      var newTask = $this.val();
      tasks.push({
        id: newId,
        title: newTask,
        status: 'active'
      });
      UpdateTasks();
      // Очистка Input
      $('#new-todo').val('');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});

/* Генерация id */

function GetNewUserId() {
  var maxId = tasks.reduce((max, item) => item.id > max ? item.id : max, 0);
  return maxId + 1;
}

/* Checkbox */

$('#todo-list').on('click', '.toggle', function(e) {
  var id = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id + 1);
  tasks[id].status = "completed";
  if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
    tasks[id].status = "active";
  }
  UpdateTasks();
});

$('#toggle-all').on('click', function() {
  $(tasks).each(function(i) {
    if ($('#toggle-all').prop("checked")) {
      tasks[i].status = "completed";
    } else {
      tasks[i].status = "active";
    }
  });
  UpdateTasks();
});

/* Отображение выбранных задач */

$('.show-all-tasks').on('click', function() {
  $('li.active').show();
  $('li.completed').show();
  $(this).toggleClass('activated');
  $('.show-active-tasks').removeClass('activated');
  $('.show-completed-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

$('.show-active-tasks').on('click', function() {
  $('li.active').show();
  $('li.completed').hide();
  $(this).toggleClass('activated');
  $('.show-all-tasks').removeClass('activated');
  $('.show-completed-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

$('.show-completed-tasks').on('click', function() {
  $('li.active').hide();
  $('li.completed').show();
  $(this).toggleClass('activated');
  $('.show-all-tasks').removeClass('activated');
  $('.show-active-tasks').removeClass('activated');
});

/* Удаление */

$('#todo-list').on('click', 'button.destroy', function(e) {

  var parentDiv = e.target.parentElement;
  var childInput = parentDiv.getElementsByClassName('toggle')[0]
  var id = childInput.getAttribute("data-id")
  var deleteElement = findIndexElement(tasks, 'id', id)
  tasks.splice(deleteElement, 1);
  console.log(deleteElement);
  UpdateTasks();
});

function ShowTasks() {
  tasks.forEach(function(item, i, tasks) {
    console.log(tasks[i].id, tasks[i].title, tasks[i].status);
  });
}

function findIndexElement(arr, propName, propValue) {
  for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
    if (arr[index][propName] == propValue)
      return index;
}


/* События кнопки Clear Completed */

$('#clear-completed').on('click', function() {
  $('input:checked').parents('li').remove();
  $(tasks).each(function(i) {
    if (tasks[i].status === "completed") {
      tasks.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
  UpdateTasks();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#todo_app {
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 130px 0 40px 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -155px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.15);
}

button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#new-todo {
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 60px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.003);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03)
}

input {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 90;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[placeholder] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

#toggle-all {
  position: absolute;
  top: -55px;
  left: -12px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
}

#toggle-all::before {
  content: "❯";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  padding: 10px 27px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 4px;
  background-color: initial;
  padding: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  font: 13px Arial;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

label[for='toggle-all'] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: default;
}

#todo-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#todo-list li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#todo-list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#todo-list li .toggle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#todo-list li input:checked::after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#bddad5" stroke-width="3"/><path fill="#5dc2af" d="M72 25L42 71 27 56l-4 4 20 20 34-52z"/></svg>');
}

#todo-list li input:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#ededed" stroke-width="3"/></svg>')
}

#todo-list li input:checked+label.text {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#todo-list li label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 15px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}

#todo-list li:hover .destroy {
  display: block;
}

#todo-list li .destroy:hover {}

#todo-list li .destroy {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #cc9a9a;
  margin: auto 0 11px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#todo-list li .destroy::after {
  content: "×";
}


/* Text footer */

#footer {
  color: #777777;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#footer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 8px 0 -3px #f6f6f6, 0 9px 1px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 16px 0 -6px #f6f6f6, 0 17px 2px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.todo-count {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.todo-count strong {
  font-weight: 300;
}

#filters {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul,
menu,
dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

#filters li {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#filters li a.activated {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

#filters li a:active {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

#filters li a:hover {
  border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.1);
}

#filters li a {
  color: inherit;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#clear-completed {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}


/* FOOTER */

footer {
  margin: auto 0;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  line-height: 1;
}

footer a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section id="todo_app">
    <header>
      <input id="new-todo" autofocus>
    </header>
    <section id="main" style="display: none;">
      <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox"> <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
      <ul id="todo-list">
      </ul>
    </section>
    <footer id="footer" style="display: none;">
      <span class="todo-count">
          <strong class="count"> </strong> items left
        </span>
      <ul id="filters">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-all-tasks">All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-active-tasks">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="show-completed-tasks">Completed</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="clear-completed" style="display: none;">Clear completed</button>
    </footer>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```